# How to POST all the options in a dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've coded together these two drop-down lists. One is full of countries and one is empty. When you click on a country and press add, the country moves to the empty drop-down list. You can do this as many times as you want.

But I'm having trouble accessing the post data of the second drop-down list when the form is submitted. Here's my code:

JavaScript:

```
function moveData(dir) {
var sF = document.getElementById(((dir == "back")?"destinationSelect":"sourceSelect"));
var dF = document.getElementById(((dir == "back")?"sourceSelect":"destinationSelect"));
if(sF.length == 0 || sF.selectedIndex == -1) return;
while (sF.selectedIndex != -1) {
    dF.options[dF.length] = new Option(sF.options[sF.selectedIndex].text, sF.options[sF.selectedIndex].value);
    sF.options[sF.selectedIndex] = null;
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<select name="sourceSelect[]" id="sourceSelect" size="5"  ondblclick="moveData(); return false;">
<optgroup label="North America">
    <option value="NORTHAMERICA_UNITEDSTATES">United States</option>
    <option value="NORTHAMERICA_BAHAMAS">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="NORTHAMERICA_BARBADOS">Barbados</option>
    <option value="NORTHAMERICA_BELIZE">Belize</option>
    <option value="NORTHAMERICA_CANADA">Canada</option>
    <option value="NORTHAMERICA_COSTARICA">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="NORTHAMERICA_CUBA">Cuba</option>
</select>   

<input type="submit" name="forward" id="button" value=">>>>" onclick="moveData(); return false;"/>
<input type="submit" name="back" id="button" value="<<<<" onclick="moveData('back'); return false;"/>

<select name="destinationSelect[]" id="destinationSelect" size="5" ondblclick="moveData('back'); return false;">
```

So yeah, I'm not sure how to post the second drop-down list when the form submits or what I need to type to see it. Like echo $_POST['destinationSelect[]'] doesn't work.

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: Nothing comes up. I'm pretty sure it's because when I move an option from one drop-down to another...it's still an option. I need to like...move it AND select it...so that it actually posts?

Comment: shouldn't there be a closing tag or at least a short close on that `optgroup`?

Comment: @AbstractChaos Yeah, you're right. It doesn't break anything but best practice does dictate a close.

Comment: `<select name="destinationSelect[]" id="destinationSelect" size="5" multiple="multiple" ondblclick="moveData('back'); return false;">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you submit your form, you need to select all the items in your second (selected) field;

```
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="submit"  onclick="selectAllOptions('destinationSelect');" />
```

then the javascript;

```
function selectAllOptions(selStr)   {
    var selObj = document.getElementById(selStr);
    for (var i=0; i<selObj.options.length; i++) {
        selObj.options[i].selected = true;
    }
}
```

otherwise they are in there but not selected

Comment: This does the trick, however I've tested it and if I add more than one country to the second dropdown, for some reason only the most recently added one is posted? any idea why?

Comment: try adding `multiple="multiple"` to the select element

Comment: `<select name="destinationSelect[]" id="destinationSelect" size="5" multiple="multiple" ondblclick="moveData('back'); return false;">`

Answer (score 2):

The values available in the `select` element are not sent when the form is submitted, just the **selected** values.

I see two choices here:

1. Add the item in the second box and automatically select it. Ugly, but it works, unless the user "un-selects" this items. I don't you to do this, though.
2. Create hidden fields to hold the values of the items. As you "move" an item to the second `select`, you also add it to the hidden field's value. This implementation is better, because it works regardless of the user messing with the second `select` (it will serve as a visual component, but won't do actual work).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The hidden fields is a good idea but if I can get Dave's answer to work, I'd rather do that, than code up the adding and removing of elements from a hidden field.

Comment: Yes, it will make a nicer "hybrid" solution.